# Magento 1.9 Action Handle not Identified

Tags: magento-1.9, module, layout

I'm facing a problem developing Magento 1.9 custom module. Magento somehow doesn't recognize the action handle in my module's layout XML file. Below is simplified code that reproduces the problem for me.

**Namespace:** MAX
**Module Name:** News

`app/code/local/MAX/News/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <max_news_news>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MAX_News</module>
                    <frontName>news</frontName>
                </args>
            </max_news_news>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <news module="MAX_News">
                    <file>max_news.xml</file>
                </news>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <news>
                <class>MAX_News_Block</class>
            </news>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/MAX/News/controllers/IndexController.php`

```
class MAX_News_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/max_news.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <!-- <frontname>_<controller>_<action> -->
    <news_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="news/featured" name="max_news_featured" template="max_news/featured.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </news_index_index>
</layout>
```

`app/code/local/MAX/News/Block/Featured.php`

```
class MAX_News_Block_Featured extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getModData()
    {
        return array('ok', 'it', 'worked');
    }
}
```

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/max_news/featured.phtml`

```
<h1 style="background: black; color:#fff;">Block template</h1>
<?php var_dump($this->getModData()) ?>
```

**Problem:**
My custom block doesn't show up on `http://site.dev/news`. But if I change the handle from `<news_index_index>` to `<max_news_news_index_index>`

(`<namespace>_<module>_<frontname>_<controller>_<action>`), it shows up. I cannot figure out where I went wrong. Might be something trivial.

I've inspected `addActionLayoutHandles()` and it indeed adds handle as `max_news_news_index_index` as a result of following line

`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php`

```
$update->addHandle(strtolower($this->getFullActionName()));
```

I've error reporting turned on and magento is in developer mode. I'm seeing no exceptions on frontend nor in logs.

Any help would be **really** appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically handle consist of

```
RouteTag_ControllerName_ActionName
```

in `config.xml`

```
    <routers>
        <max_news_news> // Your Route Tag
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>MAX_News</module>
                <frontName>news</frontName>
            </args>
        </max_news_news>
    </routers>
```

thats why your handel will be

```
<max_news_news_index_index>
```

Comment: Thta's indeed correct. Looking into `getFullActionName()` definition (why didn't I before?), `$this->getRequest()->getRequestedRouteName()` part makes up the "problem" part.